# How to compute this in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data set that looks as follows:

`y1 y2 
 1  2
 3  4
 2  5
 7  2`

and so on. So each observation is two-dimensional. Call this matrix `y`

I would like to compute

[image]

where now each `yi` is a vector.

How could I do so with R? Is there a predefined function? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have **you** tried?

Comment: I tried "cov" and "var" functions but I get different things, and searching on Google I haven't found the difference between those two :( in the worst case I was thinking of coding it adhoc but I find it nonesense if R already has a function for that

Comment: So do you have a name for what you think this computation is called? Is y-bar in the formula the mean of y1 and y2?

Comment: The formula is the covariance but the cov function in R does not give me the correct value, I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its clearly not the covariance. Let's see what it is.

y-bar is the mean of y1 and y2:

```
> d=data.frame(y1=c(1,3,2,7),y2=c(2,4,5,2))
> ybar = mean(c(d$y1, d$y2))
> ybar
[1] 3.25
```

Now inside your sum we have a slight confusion point. A * A' will depend on whether A is a row matrix or a column matrix. R just has vectors in one dimension. One way round you'll get a scalar answer, the other way round you'll get a 4x4 matrix since you have four observations. I think you want the former. So the inner bit of your sum is sums of these:

```
> t(d$y1-ybar) %*% (d$y1-ybar) 
      [,1]
[1,] 20.75
> t(d$y2-ybar) %*% (d$y2-ybar) 
     [,1]
[1,] 6.75
```

The sum is then 20.75 + 6.75 which is 27.5. There's your answer.

But these things don't care about if they are y1 or y2. These are just sum of squared difference from the mean. We can get a vector of all values using `unlist` and work with that in one:

```
> unlist(d)
y11 y12 y13 y14 y21 y22 y23 y24 
  1   3   2   7   2   4   5   2 
> sum( (unlist(d) - mean(unlist(d)) )^2 ) 
[1] 27.5
```

and there's your answer again.

Comment: but I should get a matrix. In the sum we have the product of a (2x1) times a (1x2) so we should get a (2x2) matrix or am I wrong?

Comment: Is y_i in the formula not your y1 and y2 **column vectors**? Then (y1 - ybar) is length 4. If y_i in the formula isn't that then change your notation, or make it clearer what you are doing with rows and columns. *gives up*